# Display special character in Django HTML templates

Tags: python, django

I wonder how to display special character in Django template

In models.py i have 
`chessman=models.CharField` contain for example `'&#9821;'`, what suits https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E2%99%9D, but in html templates does not replace to symbol.

It is problem in encoding on website or .py files or database? Or i have to change type?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is probably because of autoescaping. If you're sure there's nothing dodgy in your variable as well as that character, you can mark it as safe:

```
{{ myvar|safe }}
```

Comment: But unfortunately i have problem with display special characters in admin panel:

        `def __str__(self):
        return "figure: { chessman|safe }"
            .format( chessman=self.chessman)`

it return "Unresolved reference"

Comment: Well, that's a template tag, you can't use it outside a template. Use [`mark_safe`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/utils/#django.utils.safestring.mark_safe).

Comment: `from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe` (In the headline)

and
`def __str__(self): return mark_safe("figure: { chessman|safe }" .format( chessman=self.chessman))` it is works :)

Comment: Again i have similar problem... :(
Is it possible for these symbols to be displayed for example in admin site or in the form on the website on drop down list?